# I am trying to download data from Yahoo Finance using pandasb but nothing happens?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)

end = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 27)

f = web.DataReader("ugaz", 'yahoo', start, end)

f.ix['2010-01-04']
```

The above is the code I am currently trying to use to get data from Yahoo Finance. when I run the code I get this in the python shell 3.5.2 window

```
==================== RESTART: C:/Users/Zac/Desktop/ll.py ====================
```

That's all that I get. I am using python 3.5 on windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first datapoint is

```
f.ix['2012-02-08']

Open           48.360002
High           48.360002
Low            48.360002
Close          48.360002
Volume          0.000000
Adj Close    6045.000287
Name: 2012-02-08 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am not for sure what you are trying to tell me??

Comment: Man!!!!!! I feel stupid!!  Thanks it works. I am reading books on machine learning and just coping code, print was not there but I guess that is just obvious Thank You very much!!

Comment: It has been a long time since I have been on this site, Just click the green arrow to mark question correct?

Comment: Yes, here is my fav tutorial -- you will learn alot going  through it. good luck https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/IntroductionToPythonSolutions.html

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to download financial data, or any kind of data, from the web.  The script below downloads stock prices and saves everything to a CSV file.

```
import urllib2

listOfStocks = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOG", "FB", "AMZN"]

urls = []

for company in listOfStocks:
    urls.append('http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=' + company + '&d=6&e=28&f=2015&g=m&a=11&b=12&c=1980&ignore=.csv')

Output_File = open('C:/Users/your_path/Historical_Prices.csv','w')

New_Format_Data = ''

for counter in range(0, len(urls)):

    Original_Data = urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).read()

    if counter == 0:
        New_Format_Data = "Company," + urllib2.urlopen(urls[counter]).readline()

    rows = Original_Data.splitlines(1)

    for row in range(1, len(rows)):

        New_Format_Data = New_Format_Data + listOfStocks[counter] + ',' + rows[row]

Output_File.write(New_Format_Data)
Output_File.close()
```

The script below will download multiple stock tickers into one folder.

```
import urllib
import re
import json

symbolslist = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/tickers.txt").read()
symbolslist = symbolslist.split("\n")

for symbol in symbolslist:
    myfile = open("C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "w+")
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/chart/data/1D/"+ symbol+ ":US")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/symbols/" +symbol +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
        myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

Finally...this will download prices for multiple stock tickers...

```
import urllib
import re

symbolfile = open("C:/Users/your_path/Desktop/symbols/amex.txt")
symbollist = symbolfile.read()

newsymbolslist = symbollist.split("\n")

i=0
while i<len(newsymbolslist):
    url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" + newsymbolslist[i] + "&ql=1"
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    regex = '<span id="yfs_l84_' + newsymbolslist[i] + '">(.+?)</span>'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    price = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
    print "the price of ", newsymbolslist[i] , "is", price[0]
    i+=1

# Make sure you place the 'amex.txt' file in 'C:\Python27\'
```

I wrote a book about these kinds of things, and lots of other stuff.  You can find it using the URL below.

[https://www.amazon.com/Automating-Business-Processes-Reducing-Increasing-ebook/dp/B01DJJKVZC/ref=sr_1_1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DJJKVZC)?